# Estructura Array

Tags: php, sql, json

estoy realizando un proyecto, en dónde tengo que generar un array con la siguiente estructura:

```
$citas = [ [ 'hora_inicio' => '10:10', 'hora_final' => '10:40', ], [ 'hora_inicio' => '8:20', 'hora_final' => '8:50', ], ];
```

lo estoy realizando de la siguiente manera:

```
$selectCitas = $con->query("SELECT horaCita,horaFinCita FROM citas WHERE status = 1 AND fechaCita = '$fechaCita' AND sucursal = '$sucursal' AND numCabi = '$idCabina'");
while ($rowCitas = $selectCitas->fetch_assoc()) {
  array_push($cita, ["hora_inicio" => $rowCitas['horaCita'], "hora_final" => 
  $rowCitas['horaFinCita']]);   
}
```

pero al momento de realizarlo me trae lo siguiente:

```
Data": [
    {
      "hora_inicio": "10:20:00",
      "hora_final": "11:00:00"
    },
    {
      "hora_inicio": "12:20:00",
      "hora_final": "13:00:00"
    },
    {
      "hora_inicio": "14:20:00",
      "hora_final": "15:00:00"
    }
  ]
```

me lo trae por medio de llaves pero a la función que ocuparé es por medio de corchetes, me podría apoyar en estructurar esos aspectos media php

Comment: ¿quien te trae eso con llaves?  Segun parece tu consulta ya es correcta para obtener el array que deseas... ¿de donde sale eso con las llaves?

Comment: En PHP los corchetes con claves => valor, son la forma de representar propiedades de objetos. Es decir... lo que tienes estaría bien

Comment: Hola masterguru, la respuesta con llave la trae del arreglo $cita que se genera en el while, al momento de imprimir así me lo trae, con las llaves

Comment: Eso está bien así: `[{...}, {...}]`. Representa un array de objetos que podrás leer fácilmente dentro de un bucle por ejemplo. ¿Qué es lo que quieres? ¿Quieres complicarte la vida con una estructura más rebuscada que luego no podrás leer con simplicidad?

Comment: Que tal Pipe, ok mi problemas es que al momento de mandar ese array citas para realizar mi función me marca error por en otro archivos mando la estructura de los corchete y si obtenmos la respuesta

Comment: Hola A. Cedano, ok entiendo, les agredezco, pero mi detalle es que si lo mando sin llaves me marca el error mando el error que me arroja.

Comment: Es que no tienes que mandarlos sin llaves.

Comment: [15-Nov-2022 15:12:23 America/Mexico_City] PHP Warning:  array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/edisasis/public_html/Luminik_Copia/Sistema/servicios/serviciosHorarioaDisponible.php on line 100

Comment: @HarimReyes pues me interesa saber como lo has impreso, pues a mi el `print_r()` o el `var_dump()` nunca me lo ha mostrado así.  Con que instrucción consigues ver esas llaves despues de crear `$cita`?  y porque pone `Data":`?

Comment: cuando mando a llamar el arreglo con llaves me arroja este error y no me hacer la funcionanilidad indicada., , en mi funcion utilizo array_filter()

Comment: Hola masterguru lo mando a ver de la siguiente manera: echo json_encode(["Message" => "Horas Disponibles", "Status" => 1, "Tipo" => $ide, "Data" => $horariosDisponibles]);

Comment: @HarimReyes mmm... veo esto `"Data" => $horariosDisponibles`... pero no sabemos que es `$horariosDisponibles` pues no aparece en la pregunta... ¿como lo has creado?  Eso no es `$cita`... me estoy perdiendo, la verdad, lo siento

Comment: Si una disculpa es que utilizo varios arreglo pero 3 que ocupare son estos:  el arreglo $cita guardo las citas agendadas de la base de datos, $horasDisponible traigo los horarios disponible para agendar, para mandarlo a llamar es esta sentencia: echo json_encode(["Message" => "Horas Disponibles", "Status" => 1, "Tipo" => $ide, "Data" => $cita]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El `json_encode` te convierte ese **array de arrays** en un **array de objetos** para cumplir con el JSON, y segun me parece entender, a eso luego le quieres pasar un `array_filter()` en alguna parte de tu código que no vemos.

Suponiendo que la variable que usas en el `array_filter()` se llama **$json_citas**, y contiene el json creado anteriormente usando esta instrucción:

```
echo json_encode(["Message" => "Horas Disponibles", "Status" => 1, "Tipo" => $ide, "Data" => $cita]);
```

que por los motivos que sea vuelve a PHP, la forma que tienes de revertir ese formato es con **[json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php)**, pero usando el segundo parámetro en `true` de este modo:

```
$citas = json_decode($json_citas, true);
```

lo que fuerza que todo lo que contenga se convierta en **array de arrays** de nuevo, y no en *array de objetos* en PHP.

Y luego ya puedes usar la nueva variable **$citas** en el `array_filter()` sin que te aparezca ese error seguramente.

Comment: Hola que tal plasme un nuevo detalle, me podrías ayudar gracias

Comment: Si, te he leido, pero sigo sin entender lo que haces... porque tienes la necesidad de hacer el `echo $json_string;`?  donde va a parar eso?  Y aunque hagas eso, no cambia el contenido de `$citas`, la cual sigue estando en formato array de arrays.  Aquí sigue habiendo algo que se me escapa a mi o a tí.

Comment: el echo $json_string esta variable hago un json_encode ($citas) del arreglo que manod a llamar a la base de datos, solo lo hago para mostrar la información del arreglo como se estructura, mi detalle es que la función que utilizar para quitar los horarios disponible utilizar array_map y array_filter no sé si estos array hay problemas con mia rreglo de citas

Comment: no sé si me confundo por al momento de verlo me muestra las llave y en verdad en la ejecución del código si utilizar los corchete, no sé si he logrado explciarme mejor

Comment: A ver, si `solo lo hago para mostrar la información del arreglo como se estructura` entonces eso nunca lo arreglaras, porque no hay nada que arreglar, al convertirlo en json siempre va a ser de ese modo. Si quieres ver la estructura del array haz un `print_r($citas);` o si mucho me apuras ponlo así: `echo "<pre>\n";print_r($citas);echo "\n</pre>";` y lo verás mejor en un navegador y con los corchetes.

Comment: ya quedó muchas gracias, al ponerle la 2da opción que me diste pude hacer por posiciones no por un identificador, muchas gracias por la ayuda solo cambia el nombre que viene el arreglo con la posición que va el arreglo

Answer (score 0):

Esto:

```
$citas = [ [ 'hora_inicio' => '10:10', 'hora_final' => '10:40', ], [ 'hora_inicio' => '8:20', 'hora_final' => '8:50', ], ];
```

Te va a producir esto cuando intentes pasarlo a JSON:

```
[ [ "hora_inicio" : "10:10", "hora_final" : "10:40" ], [ "hora_inicio" : "8:20", "hora_final" : "8:50" ] ]
```

Y esa estructura NO es un JSON válido, lo puedes verificar [aquí](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#).

Te estás complicando la vida. Necesitas un array de objetos JSON que luego puedas leer fácilmente dentro de un bucle.

```
/*
   Para quitar verbosidad el código
   asignaré un alias a la columna de cada resultado
   para pasar directamente los datos
   usando $rowCitas
*/

$citas=array();
$selectCitas = $con->query("SELECT horaCita AS hora_inicio, horaFinCita AS hora_final FROM citas WHERE status = 1 AND fechaCita = '$fechaCita' AND sucursal = '$sucursal' AND numCabi = '$idCabina'");
while ($rowCitas = $selectCitas->fetch_assoc()) {
  $citas[] = $rowCitas;   
}
```

Aquí `$citas` será un array que, al convertirlo a JSON tendrá un JSON válido ([lo puedes verificar aquí](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#)) con esta estructura:

```
[
  {
    "hora_inicio":"10:10",
    "hora_final":"10:40"
  },
  {
    "hora_inicio":"8:20",
    "hora_final":"8:50"
  }
]
```

Esto es un array de objetos JSON que podrás consumir donde recibes la respuesta, leyéndolo por ejemplo dentro de un bucle.

Si quieres incorporarlo a otro JSON así:

```
json_encode(["Message" => "Horas Disponibles", "Status" => 1, "Tipo" => $ide, "Data" => $cita]);
```

Puedes hacerlo, simplemente agrega el elemento antes creado (lo he llamado `$citas`, no `$cita`).

```
echo json_encode(["Message" => "Horas Disponibles", "Status" => 1, "Tipo" => $ide, "Data" => $citas]);
```

---

#### Propuesta de código final

O mejor, para hacer algo más estructurado, que puedas testear, propongo el siguiente código:

```
$outPut=array("Message" => "Horas Disponibles", "Status" => 1, "Tipo" => $ide);

/*
   Para quitar verbosidad el código
   asignaré un alias a la columna de cada resultado
   para pasar directamente los datos
   usando $rowCitas
*/

$citas=array();
$selectCitas = $con->query("SELECT horaCita AS hora_inicio, horaFinCita AS hora_final FROM citas WHERE status = 1 AND fechaCita = '$fechaCita' AND sucursal = '$sucursal' AND numCabi = '$idCabina'");
while ($rowCitas = $selectCitas->fetch_assoc()) {
  $citas[] = $rowCitas;   
}
 
$outPut["Data"]=($citas) ? $citas : 'No data found';
#La línea que sigue es sólo para prueba
var_dump(json_encode($outPut));
#Esta es tu salida final
echo json_encode($outPut);
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, disculpa como podemos generar a JSON, estuve intentando convertirlo pero no pude lograrlo.

Comment: @HarimReyes revisa la respuesta editada, al final. Si necesitas incorporar `$citas` como parte de otro array, sólo tienes que ponerlo como explico al final de la respuesta.

Comment: hoal que tal plasme un nuevo comentario, me auto respondi para detallar mejor mi problema

Answer (score 0):

antemano le agradezco pero creo que no fui detallado con mi pregunta y una disculpa pondré todo el código para futuros colegas que tengan está situación.

Resumen del Proyecto:
Es un sistema de cita en dónde se estructura los horarios por medio de un intervalo de tiempo, la cita es dependiente de los servicios que tenga contratados, varias en tiempos, 30, 15,10,...,N minutos.

Un colega me ayudo a plasmar el código pero utilizo un arreglo con puros corchetes en un array, para tomar ejemplo., es aquí donde inicio el proceso.

los registro se realizan en una base de datos, para ir registrando la citas realizada y posterior obtener los espacio disponible.

tengo está consulta:

```
$selectCitas = $con->query("SELECT horaCita,horaFinCita FROM citas WHERE status = 1 AND fechaCita = '$fechaCita' AND sucursal = '$sucursal' AND numCabi = '$idCabina'");
while ($rowCitas = $selectCitas->fetch_array()) {

        $horaCita = $rowCitas['horaCita'];
        $horaFinCita = $rowCitas['horaFinCita'];

        $citas[] = array('hora_inicio'=>$horaCita,'hora_final'=>$horaFinCita);

        //$datos = 'hora_inicio' => $rowCitas['horaCita'],'hora_final' => $rowCitas['horaFinCita'];
        
        
        
        // array_push($cita, ["hora_inicio" => $rowCitas['horaCita'], "hora_final" => $rowCitas['horaFinCita']]);   
    }
```

aquí realizo mi primer arreglo en dónde traigo las horas iniciale sy finales de la base de datos.
ahora el arreglo que se uso de ejemplo tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
    $citas = [
        [
            'hora_inicio' => '10:10',
            'hora_final' => '10:40',
        ],
        [
            'hora_inicio' => '8:20',
            'hora_final' => '8:50',
        ],
    ];
```

con este arreglo se hiciera la prueba y funciono correctamente, aclaro este arreglo se puso los datos manuales.

ahora los datos que jalamos de la base de datos, genero las sentencias para generar arreglo, las que aparecen en el while.

y al momento de mandarlo a imprimir en mi página al momento de ejcutar con la siguiente sentencia:

```
$json_string = json_encode($citas);
echo $json_string;
```

y la respuesta que me manda en pantalla es la siguiente:

```
[
  {
    "hora_inicio": "10:20:00",
    "hora_final": "11:00:00"
  },
  {
    "hora_inicio": "12:20:00",
    "hora_final": "13:00:00"
  },
  {
    "hora_inicio": "14:20:00",
    "hora_final": "15:00:00"
  }
]
```

aquí mi problema son las llave ya que no me jala las estructura que se tomo de ejmplo.

aclaro que tengo otro arreglo donde maneja los horarios fraccionario, otro arreglo donde se guardará los horarios disponible y una variable donde contiene los tiempo que dura la cita, muestre el ejemplo:

```
$horariosDisponibles = [];
        $interval = 30;
        $horarios = [
            '08:00',
            '08:30',
            '09:00',
            '09:30',
            '10:00',
            '10:30',
            '11:00',
            '11:30',
        ];
```

mi problema es que no he logrado obtener la estructura del arreglo de $citas bien sin llaves, así se llama el arreglo que se van guardando los datos de la base de datos.

Una vez teniendo esos arreglo bien se ejecuta la función siguiente:

```
array_map(function ($hora) use ($citas, &$horariosDisponibles, $interval) {
            $horaParsed = strtotime($hora);
            $cita = array_filter($citas, function ($cita) use ($hora, $horaParsed, $interval) {
                return (strtotime($cita['hora_inicio']) < $horaParsed && strtotime($cita['hora_final']) > $horaParsed)
                    || (abs(((strtotime($cita['hora_inicio']) - $horaParsed) / 60)) < $interval);
            });
            if (!$cita) {
                $horariosDisponibles[] = $hora;
            }
    }, $horarios);
```

espero a verme explicado mejor y espero que me peuda ayudar con la sentencias porque me está costando trabajo obtenr los datos bien